# what is difference between two mine waiting methods

Tags: ethers.js

In Patrick Collins course, Patrick wrote a function for waiting until transaction is mined :

```js
function listenForTransactionMine(transactionResponse, provider) {
  console.log(`Mining ${transactionResponse.hash}`)
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    provider.once(transactionResponse.hash, (transactionReceipt) => {
      console.log(
        `Completed with ${transactionReceipt.confirmations} confirmations. `
      )
      resolve()
    })
  })
}
```

When I looked at the ethers documentation:

```js
// Wait for the transaction to be mined...
await tx.wait();
```

I want to ask why don't we use the second code instead of the first code.

Comment: Could you please put the code around the `listenForTransactionMine` function? To have a better idea of why that approach.

Answer (score 0):

Its more like an helper function. if you just want to wait for one transaction , you can use it as in the ether documentation.